# Converting a java game on eclipse to android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I created this game using java in eclipse (Kepler) JDK, but I want to publish it on android. I am completely new to this subject. I downloaded Android Studio as a friend suggested me to, and he told me that there were new libraries that i had to import. The game is quite complex and i imported a lot of things like color mouseevents sound and other various things , and I just want some guidelines on what i am supposed to change, or if its possible to run my game on android without changing anything from my java eclipse program.
thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to rewrite the entire UI and input handling code.  Android does not use the standard Java UI.  You should start out by reading tutorials on basic android architecture, the activity lifecycle, and views.

Comment: But anything with graphics can stay the same?

Comment: Probably not.  If you used openGL, then you're likely good.  If you used standard Java GUI elements, you'll have to recode.  The image files themselves (pngs, jpgs, etc) would be good of course.

Comment: is there like a site that has an exact "translation" of the libraries that are different between android and java eclipse

Comment: And in your opinion would it take a large amount of changes to change the code or would i have to rework my algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Totally agreed with @Gabe Sechan that you have to rewrite most of the code which would be compatible with Android. One of framework which support Java language and used to create games(mostly 2D) for most of the platforms is [Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/index.html). You can go through that framework if it can help.